# Can BlackBerry virtual goods be transferred between devices?

Tags: blackberry, in-app-purchase

I am developing a BlackBerry app in which users can purchase virtual goods (such as sounds and images) using their BlackBerry App World login details.

If the user changes their phone to another BlackBerry, are they able to transfer these virtual goods to their new phone without having to re-purchase them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlackBerry App World allows to re-download purchased application when a user changes device. I think the same approach will work for digital goods.